# Does Bulma Buefy support VUE 3?

Tags: vue.js, buefy

Does Bulma Buefy support VUE 3? I am trying to install buefy but I am running into this error.
[This is the error I am facing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8FZB.png)

Comment: No buefy does not support Vue 3. Check this issue: https://github.com/buefy/buefy/issues/2505

Comment: [No, it does not.](https://github.com/buefy/buefy/issues/2505#issuecomment-997000720)

Comment: Some people seem to think oruga is the next logical step from buefy in vue 3

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In quick start guide in Buefy they wrote :

> Quick start You need Vue.js version 2.6+. (Vue 3 is not supported)

So it does not support Vue3.