# [Vue warn]: failed to resolve component: b-field

Tags: vue.js, codepen, buefy

I'm trying to create a codepen example to reproduce a CSS issue.  However, I've run into a problem when creating the codepen itself.  It is not recognizing Buefy's `b-field` component - in the console this warning appears:
[image]

In the codpen Settings these packages have been included:
https://unpkg.com/vue@next
https://unpkg.com/buefy/dist/buefy.min.css

Here's a [link](https://codepen.io/knot22/pen/LYdyORm) to the codepen.

And here's the code within the codepen:

JS

```
const app = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      data: { "description": "lantern", "price": "15.75" }
    }
  }
});

app.mount('#demo');
```

HTML

```
<div id="demo">
  
  <!-- using Bulma classes -->
  <div class="field is-horizontal">
    <div class="field-label is-normal">
      <label class="label">Purchase price of {{ data.description }}:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="field-body">
      <div class="field">
        {{ data.price }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- using Buefy component -->
  <b-field horizontal label="Purchase Price of Lantern:">{{ data.price }}</b-field>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.is-horizontal {
  background-color: yellow;
  color: red;
}

.field-label {
  text-align: left;
  background-color: lightblue;

  /* specify width */
  /*flex-grow: 2;*/   /* overwrites default value of 1 */
  min-width: 30%;

  /* center text vertically */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: -5px;
}
```

How can this warning be resolved so the Buefy component works in the codepen example?

Comment: You always need to import a component in the file it is used, or globally to be able to use it in any component. Presumably it is as simple as a `Vue.use(Buefy)` per https://buefy.org/documentation/start/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing javascript part of Buefy. You also need to include

```
https://unpkg.com/buefy/dist/buefy.min.js
```

However, doing bit further research, it seems currently Buefy supports only Vue version 2.x.

Comment: Add this dependency and making minor JS adjustments fixed the issue!

Answer (score 3):

Buefy doesn't work yet with Vue3.

In their usage example, it becomes obvious from this line:

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2"></script>
```

Admittedly, they could be more assertive about this limitation but, then again, it's not something to brag about, since Vue 3 has been out for quite some time.

Here are a few discussions around the same topic:

- https://github.com/buefy/buefy/issues/2505
- [Does Bulma Buefy support VUE 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71879603/does-bulma-buefy-support-vue-3)

---

List of dependencies to make Buefy work in codepen:
(disclaimer: I got them from [this pen](https://codepen.io/ratracegrad/pen/KKomqPp))

CSS:

- https://unpkg.com/buefy/dist/buefy.min.css

JS:

- https://unpkg.com/vue@2/dist/vue.min.js
- https://unpkg.com/buefy/dist/buefy.min.js

---

According to the [Getting started: Standalone](https://buefy.org/documentation/start#standalone) section, all you need (besides latest Vue 2) are the buefy css and js files.
To me, that means the Buefy js file looks for `window.Vue` global and registers itself as a plugin to it (therefore you don't have to do it).

Comment: Ah ha!  I'll adjust the codepen Settings to use Vue 2.6.11.  Thanks for identifying the problem.

Comment: I think you're safe to go with latest `@2`: `//unpckg.com/vue@2/dist/vue.min.js`. Here's a [Buefy codepen](https://codepen.io/ratracegrad/pen/KKomqPp), look at it's deps. I'm not sure all of them are required (e.g: lodash, axios), but the ones for vue and buefy are the ones you want. Added them to the answer.